# Setting the Column Choices in a Google Form Multi Choice Grid Item?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have been struggling to get the correct code to set the Column Choices in a Google Form Multi Choice Grid. My code keeps giving me the debug error

> TypeError: Cannot find function setColumns in object Item. (line 26, file "Populate Hazard Choices").

I've tried setColumnChoices and setColumns and seem to have the same bad results.

```
function PopulateHazardChoices(){

// call the form and connect to the Question Item
  var form = FormApp.openById("FakeFormID");  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("fakeItemID");

// identify the sheet Hazard Choices needed to populate the question selections
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DataFactors = ss.getSheetByName("DataFactors");

// grab the Hazards in the first column of the sheet from the Group of Hazard Choices
  // use sheet Row Number for First Hazard in the group of choices; use 1 as the index column A; number of rows included in range
  // 7,1,3 would be Row 7, Column A, 4 rows in the range - therefore A7 through A10

  // [Conditions of Runway] Hazard Group
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(7,1,4);
  var HazardSelections = [];

// convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < HazardValues.length; i++)    
    if(HazardValues[i][0] != "")
      HazardSelections[i] = HazardSelections[i][0];

// populate the Wind Question with the array data
  QuestionItem.setColumns(HazardSelections);
}
```

The plan is to have the Grid Columns be populated from a Sheet called "DataFactors" so that any changes to the list of hazards will populate exactly the same on the Form. When the user submits a Form, the choices are compared to the sheet and a point value is assigned. Hopefully this will solve a problem with mis-compares between the Form submissions and the Hazard values.
I have had good results using Dropdown lists but can't seem to make the method work for Multi Choice Grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is for a new item

From [Class GridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item)

```
// Open a form by ID and add a new grid item.
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var item = form.addGridItem();
item.setTitle('Rate your interests')
    .setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
    .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
```

If the item already exists, then once you get the item and before using `setColumns`, you should use [asGridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asGridItem()) of the Interface Item.

```
var gridItem = QuestionItem.asGridItem();
gridItem.setColumns(HazardSelections);
```

Comment: Ruben, your code uses the same SetColumns as mine with the exception of the array variable. Do you have some specific advise to help clarify what might be wrong with my example? Thanks, Jack

Comment: @JohnGainer It looks that you are missing `var item = form.addGridItem();`

Comment: Ruben, declaring the variable .asGridItem() did the trick. Great catch, it would have taken me forever to find that. I had to do a tiny bit of work on the array but it's working great now. I can now repeat the same for each Hazard Group in the DataFactors sheet. Is it appropriate in this forum to post the final code for others to see? Thanks so much, Jack

Comment: Here is an extract of the working code

// Condition of Flight - Hazard Group A2 through A4
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(2,1,3).getValues();  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("fakeID1").asGridItem();
  QuestionItem.setColumns(HazardValues);
  //End of Hazard Group  

// Conditions of Runway - Hazard Group A7 through A10
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(7,1,4).getValues();  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("fakeID2").asCheckboxItem();
  QuestionItem.setChoiceValues(HazardValues);
  //End of Hazard Group

}

Comment: @JohnGainer Post it as answer. Comments are intended to be have a short live (they could be deleted "soon").

Answer (score 0):

Ruben, Thanks for the help. Here is the completed scripts with a few different types of Form Items (Grid, CheckboxGrid and MultipleChoice).
Thanks,
Jack

```
function PopulateHazardChoices(){

// call the sheet and form needed to populate the question selections
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DataFactors = ss.getSheetByName("RiskValues");  
  var form = FormApp.openById("FakeFormID");

// For each Group of Hazard Choices - repeat the folowing
  // identify the Hazards in Column A of the sheet for each Group of Hazard Choices 
     // Use Row Number for First Hazard in the Group of Harard Choices
     // Use 1 as the index Column A
     // Number of rows included in the Group
     // 2,1,3 would be Row 2, Column A, 3 rows in the range - therfore A2 through A4
  //declare QuestionItem including type of item i.e. .asGridItem();  
  // populate the Question with the array data

// Crew Compliment - Hazard Group A3 through A5
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(3,1,3).getValues();  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("FakeItemID").asGridItem();
  QuestionItem.setColumns(HazardValues);
  //End of Hazard Group

// pAve Rotorcraft - Hazard Group A40 through A43
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(40,1,4).getValues();  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("FakeItemID").asCheckboxGridItem();
  QuestionItem.setColumns(HazardValues);
  //End of Hazard Group

// paVe Runway Length - Hazard Group A72 through A75
  var HazardValues = DataFactors.getRange(72,1,4).getValues();  
  var QuestionItem = form.getItemById("FakeItemID").asMultipleChoiceItem();
  QuestionItem.setChoiceValues(HazardValues);
  //End of Hazard Group


} //End function PopulateHazardChoices

// Edit Journal - Created December 2019, Jack Gainer, TSTC Chief Pilot
  // Initial Implentation Tests - January 2019
  // Add remaiining Hazard Group setValues code - February 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

This satisfactorily inserts columns and rows from Google Sheets to a Google Forms Multiple Choice Grid item:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('MyForm');
var PtjGridList = form.getItemById("MyGridItem Eg.4158415230").asGridItem();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MySpreadsheet");
var PtjNombre = ss.getSheetByName("MySheet");
var RowValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 5, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
var ValuesRow = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)
if(RowValues[i][0] != "")
ValuesRow[i] = RowValues[i][0];
PtjGridList.setRows(ValuesRow)
var ColumnValues = PtjNombre.getRange(2, 6, PtjNombre.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
var ValuesColumn = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++)
if(ColumnValues[i][0] != "")
ValuesColumn[i] = ColumnValues[i][0];
PtjGridList.setColumns(ValuesColumn)
```

Hope it helps.